# Date/DateTime Filters on client side JSON Model

Tags: javascript, sapui5, jsonmodel

I have a JSON model that is bound to a sap.m.Table. I am trying to filter data based on a column "Date" (bound to property[**CreatedOn**] of the model) which the service returns in the JSON Object Format **("/Date(timeStamp)")**. The table is as below:
[image]

sample Date from server:

[image]

I am trying to filter the table on the **client side** but I am not sure on how to implement date filters on the client side. The date displayed are formatted based on

> sap.ui.model.type.Date({pattern: 'dd/MM/YYYY'})

The filtering code looks as below:

```js
var fromD = this.getView().byId("idKMFilterPaneDocDateF").getValue() ? new Date(this.getView().byId("idKMFilterPaneDocDateF").getValue()) :
  undefined;

var dtFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
  path: "CreatedOn",
  operator: "EQ",
  value1: "dateTime'" + fromD.toJSON() + "'"
});

var binding = oTable.getBinding("items");
binding.filter([filter], "Application");
binding.refresh();
```

When I execute the above code, I always get "NO Data". I need to implement the "BT" filters as well based on user selection criteria but can't get it to work with "EQ" itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create Custom Filter**

```
var fromD = this.getView().byId("idKMFilterPaneDocDateF").getValue() ? new Date(this.getView().byId("idKMFilterPaneDocDateF").getValue()) :undefined;
var dtFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("CreatedOn");
dtFilter.fnTest = function(value) {
    //check what value are you getting here. If its string, get only time out of it
    //Compare the date values(in milliseconds)
    fromD.setHours(0); //get rid of time and concern about date
    fromD.setMinutes(0);
    fromD.setSeconds(0);
    fromD.setMilliseconds(0);
    //value should be date object, else change accordingly..
   if(fromD.getTime() === value.getTime()){
       return true;
   }
   return false;
};
```

*PS:If you can get working JSFiddle with your coding context, I could debug.*